# Sustituir/Remplazar ids masivamente

Tags: python, json, matrices, id, replace

Tengo un json en el que cuento con multitud de ids que tienen que ser sustituidos por otros diferentes para posteriormente ser importados.

Por mi parte puedo generar una matriz del tipo:

| Nombre | id_origina | id_nuevo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| objeto1 | 12345 | 33333 |
| objeto2 | 67890 | 44444 |

¿Alguna idea de como hacer este cambio de forma masiva?

JSON Ejemplo

```
{"rules":[{"id":2,"clientKey":"com.codebarrel.tenant.global","name":"Esta es una prueba","state":"ENABLED","canOtherRuleTrigger":false,"notifyOnError":"FIRSTERROR","authorAccountId":"JIRAUSER10000","actorAccountId":"JIRAUSER10000","created":1668680391098,"updated":1668680391098,"trigger":{"id":"29","component":"TRIGGER","schemaVersion":1,"type":"jira.manual.trigger.issue","value":{"groups":[]},"children":[],"conditions":[],"optimisedIds":[],"newComponent":false},"components":[{"id":"30","component":"ACTION","schemaVersion":6,"type":"jira.issue.edit","value":{"operations":[{"fieldId":"customfield_10200","fieldType":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:textarea","type":"SET","value":"esta es una prueba"}],"sendNotifications":true,"useLegacyRendering":false},"children":[],"conditions":[],"optimisedIds":[],"newComponent":false}],"projects":[],"labels":[],"tags":[]}],"cloud":false}
```

Comment: ¿En base a qué se generan los nuevos ID? ¿Aleatoriamente? ¿Secuencia?

Comment: y en que lenguaje quieres hacer eso?

Comment: Son totalmente aleatorios, no cuentan con ningún  tipo de orden

Comment: @masterguru, realmente busco opciones o herramientas, entiendo que con python se debería poder hacer algo

Comment: debes especificarlo para que te puedan ayudar... cada lenguaje trata a los json de forma distinta con funciones distintas y no te podemos dar una solución si no sabemos cual vas a usar... eso se puede hacer con cualquier lenguaje seguramente. Lo digo para agregar la etiqueta correcta a tu pregunta y que llame más la atención a los que dominen el lenguaje que quieres usar.

Comment: Mismamente con python, ya que unicamente necesito modificar el json para importarlo en una herramienta.

Comment: también ayudaria que pusieras una porcion o el json entero que vas a cambiar, para determinar su estructura y ver si con unos sed/awk/grep en un archivo bash se soluciona a nivel de terminal

Comment: Puedes modificar tu pregunta agregando esa porción del json pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta.

Comment: Ya he añadido un ejemplo simple, el ID a modificar seria el de "customfield_10200".

Comment: Me he entretenido haciendolo en javascript.  En [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/5xcgm9an/) puedes jugar con el. (No es una respuesta, ha sido un ejercicio que he hecho para mi solamente pero quizás te sea útil... de hecho tu pregunta carece de ningún intento y debería ser cerrada por ello, je)